# Request para ASP.NET MCV super lento

Tags: .net, mvc, debug, request

Tenho um problema complicado no meu projeto, e já não sei o que fazer mais. Tenho um projeto MVC4 (após um upgrade do projeto MVC3 que a empresa onde trabalho já tinha) e está a tornar-se quase impossível de fazer debug através do VS2013. Os requests chegam a demorar 5/7/10 minutos, mas as vezes, passado já algum tempo, tudo começa a funcionar relativamente rápido. Deixo em baixo uma screenshot das ferramentas de debug do Chrome, na aba Network.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, os meus requests ficam assim durante muito tempo. Se correr o projeto sem debug, corre sem problemas aparente.

Note que eu tenho serviços WCF que estão no meu IIS que são acedidos pelo meu projeto MVC do UI, ao qual estou a fazer o debug.

O que poderá ser? Obrigado.

Comment: Acredito que esse problema seja comum, pois fiz uma busca no SO em inglês e encontrei uma resposta com muitos votos positivos. Espero que ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow

Comment: Por acaso já me tinha deparado com essa questão/resposta, mas o meu problema não são os símbolos, isso ele carrega rapido. Penso que devo ter algo mal no IIS server. Vou colocar mais detalhes na pergunta.